# Batch file - add file name to first row of txt

Tags: batch-file

I'm working with batch files for the first time for a specific need. I have several txt files, each with many rows of data. I need to add the file name to the first row of each txt file. 
From searching and playing around, the closest I have is:

```
@echo off 
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
:: store modified files in subdirectory 'Processed'
md Processed
for %%a in (*.txt) do (
>temp echo %%a
copy temp+%%a Processed\"%%a"
)
```

When I run this, the file name is added but the formatting is ruined (spaces between all characters and the returns seem to be removed). Am I missing some simple formatting somewhere??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your for loop should look like this.

The first line writes the filename into the destination.

The second line appends the entire file with no modification into the destination.

```
for %%a in (*.txt) do (
 echo %%a > "Processed\%%a"
 type %%a >> "Processed\%%a"
)
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply. That didn't seem to do it unfortunately, that opened the original txt (in notepad) and created a txt in the Processed dir with only the file name

Comment: you can try it with 'type' as the active command.  That used to be the equivalent of 'cat' in unix.  I edited the answer to demonstrate it's use.

Comment: That did the trick, thanks for the help! Final code added to original post for future reference for others.

Comment: @TheDOSandDONTS, don't add the final code to the question, that violates the question-and-answer style of this site! If you want to post your final code write an answer instead!

Comment: @webmite, your quotation is not good, you should do it like `> "Processed\%%a"` instead; furthermore, `echo "%%a" >` also returns the quotation marks plus the trailing space, so you should change that to `> "Processed\%%a" echo(%%a`...

Comment: @aschipfl you are correct. I have made the corrections you suggested after testing on my system. My original recommendations were just from memory without testing.

Comment: @aschipfl Thanks for the assistance with this (and note about answers in the original question).

Comment: The revised code is working well for my original question. I'm now up against another problem. The txt file has tab delimited fields, but I need them changed to another character (ideally a comma or semicolon). Some searches have come up with using a JPERL.bat script, but if it is reasonably possible I would prefer to keep it all within the same BAT file. Would that be an option?

Comment: That is really a separate question and should be asked as such. Part of the pre-requisite on this question was to minimize the changes in the target files other than adding a header.  If you ask a new question and drop a pointer to it here I will be able to follow and reply.